# How to define boost python version when using vcpkg?

Tags: boost-python, vcpkg

Does anybody have any experience with defining the python version of boost-python when installing from vcpkg?
I'm trying to use OpenVDB's python interface, and while I can get it working with the default python39 boost library, I'm not able to figure out how to define which boost-python version to install with vcpkg, and/or don't know how to define the correct parameters for the cmake command line to specify a python version at that point.

The default library that boost uses is 3.9, but as I'm typically in Anaconda, and 3.9 is not a standard download, I wanted to hold the boost library to be 3.8 instead.

I've commented in the github issues for openvdb, https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb/issues/946
but as this is not an issue with that project, and more of a dependencies thing, I thought I'd ask here in case you seen this on your travels :)

Thanks in advance for your time.
Neil

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem right now... did you get it solved?

Comment: No, dropped it.  Your message is a good time to revisit.  Will reply here with the next attempt with the latest version.